# How can I determine the type of a particular drive without using letters of it (for drive which not initialized or not formated)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Sorry for my bad English.

I am looking for solutions to detect this type of disk device in C/C++. I found the **GetDriveType("Letter_of_Disk")** function, but it required that device to format and have a drive letter. So, I can not get information of disk which not initialized or not formated.

```
        switch (GetDriveType("D:"))
        {
        case DRIVE_FIXED:
        {
            //Your Drive is an Internal HDD/SSD/Nvme or Portable/External HDD/SSD/Nvme
        }
        case DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
        {
            //Your Drive is an USB Flash or USB Pen
        }
        case DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR:
        {
            //
        }
        case DRIVE_REMOTE:
        {
            //
        }
        case DRIVE_CDROM:
        {
            //
        }
        case DRIVE_RAMDISK:
        {
            //
        }
        case DRIVE_UNKNOWN:
        {
            //
        }
        }
```

There is a way to use "**\\.\PhysicalDriveX**" as "Letter_of_Disk", where **X** is the device index ?.

Prefer to use Win32API, not WMI.

Thanks.

Comment: in what problem call `GetDriveType(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDriveX\\")` ?

Comment: Thank @RbMm . It is OK. In my case, X is integer variable ( ex: int my_disk_index; ). How to merge L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDriveX\\" with my_disk_index ?.

Comment: That is a fairly simple piece of C++ string manipulation for which a websearch would reveal the answer.

Comment: `swprintf_s(buf, cch, L"\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive%u\\", index)` ?

Comment: @RbMm Thank you so much. My problem is solved. :)